# JavaScript contenteditable selection endOffset returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I am trying to use endOffset to get the selection area of a contenteditable div however as there is always a trailing `<br>` within the last paragraph, upon the user selecting all paragraphs endOffset returns the wrong value. This is also the case if other markup is within the last paragraph.

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>Line One</p>
    <p>Line Two</p>
    <p>Line Three</p>
    <p>Line Four<br></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
if (range.endOffset == range.endContainer.textContent.length)
{
  // Do Something
}
```

Is there a way I can see if the selection reaches the end?

Thanks